# Possible to get the file-path of the class that called a method in Java?

Tags: java, file, io, path, libraries

Let's say for instance I have this scenario

> C:\Users\Name\Documents\Workspace\Project\Src\Com\Name\Foo.java

```
Public class Foo {

    public Foo() {
        Bar b = new Bar();
        b.method();
    }
}
```

Then lets say that class Bar is in a .JAR file that's being used as a library, is it possible to figure out where the class that called method() was from? (in this case, the Foo class)

I've done a little looking around Google and can't find anything, and this code would definately simplify my library quite a bit.

Comment: Foo.class.getResource("Foo.class")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get path of the caller class file from inside the method Bar#method then you can use something like this:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
String callerFilePath = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(stackTrace[1].getClassName().replace('.', '/') + ".class"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the path from where the file is being executed. For example, you have the file :
**C:\Users\Name\Documents\Workspace\Project\Src\Com\Name\Foo.java**

After compiling, it will change to :
**C:\Users\Name\Documents\Workspace\Project\Src\Com\Name\Foo.class**

You can use this to get the directory of the file:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

and then you can add this String to it:

```
String cPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Foo.class";
```

Thus, **cPath** would be the complete path to the file.

Comment: This is not doing what I'm asking, sorry if I wasn't clear, I want to get the class that called the method, So if Jake.class calls a method in Jim.class, I want to return to path of Jake.class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Foo.class.getResource("Foo.class")` to get the location of the compiled class file. The question is, how will this help you simplify your library?