# Java get absolute path of file from stack trace

Tags: java, debugging, stdout

I have a Java print stack trace function that I use for debugging.

```
private static void printError(String message, Significance severityLevel, int stackTraceStart) {
    final String thread_name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    final String location_of_print_statement = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[stackTraceStart].toString();
    Package_Private.printLineToReadout("\n" + "Thread \"" + thread_name + "\": "
            + location_of_print_statement + "\n" + message, ReadoutCondition.BAD, severityLevel);
}
```

Problem is that it only prints "modules.ShopModule.configure(ShopModule.scala:8)"

I want it to print the entire path to that file, not the relative path.

Comment: Relative path would be good; any path in addition to the filename.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit too late, but might be useful for someone else. 
You can use the ClassLoader to search for the resource corresponding to a specific class file.

```java
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.net.URL;

public class Abs {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Arrays.asList(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()).stream().forEach(e -> {
      String cn = e.getClassName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
      URL u = new Abs().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(cn);
      out.println("" + u.toString().replace(".class", ".java") + ":" + e.getLineNumber());
    });
  }
}
```

Similar discussion is here: [Possible to get the file-path of the class that called a method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674037/possible-to-get-the-file-path-of-the-class-that-called-a-method-in-java) and here [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)